# Is the term "KTV" in use in any English-speaking country?

Tags: etymology, history, abbreviations, initialisms

While travelling recently for two months in mainland China I noticed many buildings with the English letters ***KTV*** in their signage.

At first I thought this was something to do with company names or such and had no idea what the usually very gaudy buildings were for. Later I learned they were Karaoke places and still wondered about the Latin letters common in their signs.

I finally discovered that **KTV** is widely believed to be an English term originating in an abbreviation of **Karaoke Television**. I found this to be quite odd as I'm a middle aged native English speaker and have travelled in the majority of the other English speaking countries of the world but had never seen this term before. In fact to me it has the feel of "foreigner English" a bit like the German term ***Handy*** and many Japanese terms, which look like English, are believed by many speakers of those languages to be English, but are not used, or do not have same meaning, by native English speakers.

I've also travelled in Taiwan and it's used there alongside "卡拉OK". I've also travelled in Korea and Japan, which each have their own terms and haven't seen **KTV** used in either country.

It does get Google hits in English speaking countries, but not many and, without further evidence, I assume it is infrequently used for Asian-themed karaoke places, or places run by and targeting Asian customers, in western countries.

But I don't know everything, so maybe this is widely used by native English speakers in some English-speaking part of the world that I never ran into.

Does anybody know the true origin and history of this term? Is it really used in English? Is it only used in "foreigner English"? Could it be due to some brand or product name in some Asian country that became genericised? - I believed that's how Germany got **Handy**.

---

I'm now (early 2015) travelling in Cambodia and have found that KTV is the usual term here too, though karaoke is also used. I kept an eye out for it in Malaysia, Thailand, and Laos and only saw it occasionally at Chinese style places.

[image: KTV sign in Mongolian and Chinese in Inner Mongolia, China]
<sup>KTV sign in Mongolian and Chinese in Inner Mongolia, China</sup>

[image: KTV sign in Zhangjiakou, China]
<sup>KTV sign in Zhangjiakou, China</sup>

[image: KTV sign in English and Chinese in Malaysia]
<sup>KTV sign in Chinese in Malaysia</sup>

[image: KTV sign in Khmer and Chinese in Cambodia]
<sup>KTV sign in Khmer and Chinese in Cambodia</sup>

Comment: I think this kind of borrowing-with-a-slight-change-in-meaning-and-usage is quite common. English borrows like that as well; examples that come to mind are _rsvp_, which is used as a verb (I've even seen "rsvp, please") or "table d'hote" meaning "set menu".

Comment: It appears that [KTV](http://acronyms.thefreedictionary.com/KTV) is mainly used in [China](http://www.singledudetravel.com/2011/04/karaoke-chinese-style-aka-ktv/). It is possible that it *may* have a [different meaning](http://www.shanghaiexpat.com/phpbbforum/what-is-a-ktv-t112994.html) to some.

Comment: Oh yes it's definitely common. *Television* could be a prime English example made of pieces from classical languages. So far I've found Chinese to be strongly against the very idea it's not English though, such as deleting mentions of it from Wiktionary!

Comment: I travel extensively around the globe and I've honestly never noticed nor seen this before. I'll keep an eye out the next time I traverse through the orient.

Comment: I haven't heard of it in England or the rest of the UK.

Comment: How do the Chinese pronounce KTV? Is it letter per letter, or one single word? Do the Chinese pronounce the alphabet, quasi phonetically (as the Italians do) or as English native speakers do?

Comment: @Mari-LouA: They pronounce it letter by letter. There are a couple of questions on sister sites about the details of how Chinese pronounce English acronyms: [How do Chinese people pronounce Latin characters?](http://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/2724) ・ [Do acronyms borrowed from English use neutral tone (aka tone 0 or tone 5) for all syllables?](http://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/721)

Comment: If you could post an image of those signs that would be great :)

Comment: @Mari-LouA: Done. But not from China yet since I accidentally deleted my tag index for my China photos a few months ago )-:

Comment: Love the first pic, and the "GoGo". Is that a strip club btw?

Comment: @Mari-LouA: It was a seedy looking place at the end of a mostly otherwise failed pier development in Malacca. I didn't go inside but in (at least) China, Laos, and Cambodia places called KTV or karaoke seem to be akin to brothels. It's easy to Google about the phenomenon. So it's quite possible.

Comment: Well after wondering about this for about a year, I'm finally finding evidence that it began in Taiwan in the mid-to-late 1980s as an offshoot of movie-watching parlours there that were called "MTV" for "movie television" or perhaps "music & TV". Not affiliated with the cable music channel but perhaps inspired by it since it began in 1981. (If you Google MTV and KTV together you'll find stuff that I'm slowly reading through before I consider attempting an answer.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The origin seems clear enough: an abbreviation for *karaoke television*. Whether or not the average person in China understands the origin is probably not relevant as to its popularity; after all, I think relatively few Americans could write out the long form for *RSVP*.

Several years ago, it was widely reported in anglophone media that some arm of the Chinese government was trying to [discourage the use of roman acronyms](http://blogs.wsj.com/chinarealtime/2010/04/07/fyi-to-cctv-no-english-acronyms/) like NBA (but not [Q](http://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?p=2252)?), and while I think this is probably an example of press misunderstanding or exaggeration, the reports acknowledge that various acronyms are commonly used in China— indeed that various organs of the Chinese state itself are [best known by their English abbreviations](http://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?p=2271), like CCTV and SARFT.

---

*KTV* returns zero results from the British National Corpus, and the one entry in the Corpus of Contempotary American English is the name of a television news show. So I turn to the [Corpus of Global Web-Based English (GloWbE)](http://corpus2.byu.edu/glowbe/), which turns up the following results by country:

- Singapore 67
- Hong Kong 35
- The Philippines 20
- Malaysia 6

Almost all of these refer to karaoke or karaoke parlors, so depending on your standard for "English-speaking country," it does seem to be in use in Singapore, Hong Kong, the Philippines, and Malaysia.

There are 8 results for the US, of which 5 come from websites about China and three come from travel blogs about China. The 11 results for the UK, similarly, are about travel in China or entertainment in China. In both cases, *KTV* is invariably described as the local name for a karaoke parlor.

In contrast, results for *karaoke* alone show

- GB 867
- US 528
- Singapore 233
- Malaysia 235
- Philippines 198
- Hong Kong 174

In fact, there are even more results for *noraebang* (the more obscure Korean term for the same entertainment; venues are signed with *NRB*) in Singapore than for *KTV* in either the US or UK corpora. The Google Books results for *KTV*, similarly, refer exclusively to karaoke parlors as they exist in China, Taiwan, or Southeast Asia.

The Yelp category is *karaoke* (though *KTV* turns up in some reviews, along the lines of *This place reminds me of a KTV/karaoke place in Guangzhou*). For Google Maps/Google Local in my area, there are 414 results for *karaoke*, and only 3 of any kind for *KTV*, only one of which is for a karaoke joint.

All of this suggests very strongly to me that *KTV* as a term referring to a karaoke establishment is not a mainstream usage in the US (and does not seem to be in the UK or Canada, either), though expats or tourists might use it, and any businesses catering to them.

Comment: Actually the origin is not so clear after all, as is often the case with acronyms and abbreviations the expansion is only part of the story. It turns out it comes from Taiwan where it was a modification of an early related abbreviation, MTV "movie television" or "movies & TV". This was used for establishments where people would pay to use a private booth to watch TV or movies on video cassette or videodisc. These have now disappeared but KTV expanded to a massive scale once it got to mainland China.

Comment: Other English abbreviations I've only ever heard in the Sinosphere are MV and APP.

Answer (score 1):

Never heard of it, native AmE (California/Indiana). Google search brings up a [few](http://www.musictunnelktv.com/HomeENG.asp) [hits](http://www.brooklyndaily.com/stories/2014/18/all-k-tv-trojan-horse-2014-04-25-bk_2014_18.html) of karaoke places called "KTV" in the US, but given the prevalence of the name that you report in China, I'm guessing those US locations imported it from China rather than vice versa.